# How to Fix "java.lang.NullPointerException" at org.kie.internal.io.ResourceFactory.newFileResource

Tags: aws-lambda, drools

I'm getting a null pointer exception while trying to create a new session:

> java.lang.NullPointerException kContainer.newKieSessiona using AWS Lambda (java .jar file) + Drools Rule Engine.]

```
  public class LambdaRequestHandler implements RequestHandler<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(String input, Context context) {
        context.getLogger().log("Input: " + input);
        int rulesFired = 0;
        try {
            KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
            KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
            KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession("ksession-rules");
            Account account = new Account(200);
            account.withdraw(150);
            kSession.insert(account);
            rulesFired = kSession.fireAllRules();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "Rules Fired - " + rulesFired;
    }
}

Rules.drl file

package rules

import Account

rule "accountBalanceCheck1"
  when
  $account : Account( balance < 100 )
  then
  System.out.println("Inside rule 1");
end

kmodule.xml file

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kmodule xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule">
    <kbase name="rules" packages="rules">
        <ksession name="ksession-rules"/>
    </kbase>
    <kbase name="rules2" packages="rules">
        <ksession name="statelessSession" type="stateless" default="true"/>
    </kbase>
    <kbase name="dtables" packages="dtables">
        <ksession name="ksession-dtables"/>
    </kbase>
    <kbase name="process" packages="process">
        <ksession name="ksession-process"/>
    </kbase>
</kmodule>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?